# Query on facedetection code

Tags: c

Could someone explain what is happening in the following code?

```
if( strncmp( argv[i], cascade_opt, cascade_opt_len) == 0 )
                cascade_name = argv[i] + cascade_opt_len;
```

My guess is that this two lines check what kind of cascade has been keyed in by user(hence argv[i]) and then if the first cascade_opt_len characters are the same, it concatenates argv[i] and cascade_opt_len.  However, this does not seem to make sense to me as why concatenate a name with an integer?

Also,

```
if( argv[i][nested_cascade_opt_len] == '=' )
```

I always thought the most argv[i] can be is a one dimensional array which records down what the user keys in. But somehow this line makes it seem like argv[i] can be a 2D array. Anyone able to enlighten me on what it actually means?

Comment: yes but unfortunately I do not have enough points to vote up because I'm new so I said thanks manually:(

Comment: You may not have enough rep to vote up, but you always have enough rep to accept an answer as the most helpful to you (even if the question is closed), and accepting an answer gives you a little rep (2 points), helping you reach the level where you can vote up.

Comment: Oh.oops sorry I just realised that we can click on the tick to accept an answer (>_<) was too busy trying to press the voting button. Thanks for the info (^v^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cascade_name = argv[i] + cascade_opt_len;
```

`argv` is of type `char **`. Indexing it means that `argv[i]` is of type `char *`—i.e., a string. Adding an integer to a `char *` advances the pointer by so many characters. This could be written perhaps more clearly as this:

```
cascade_name = &argv[i][cascade_opt_len];
```

It trims the first `casecade_opt_len` characters off of the *i*th argument `argv[i]` and assigns the remaining string to `cascade_name`.

---

```
if( argv[i][nested_cascade_opt_len] == '=' )
```

`argv` is an array of strings, so `argv[i]` is the *i*th argument and `argv[i][nested_cascade_opt_len]` is the character at index `nested_cascade_opt_len`. This checks if that character an the equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( strncmp( argv[i], cascade_opt, cascade_opt_len) == 0 )
        ^              ^             ^
```

this probably checks that argv[i] constants first substring equals to  `cascade_opt` and `cascade_opt_len` is length of `cascade_opt`

In next line:

```
        cascade_name = argv[i] + cascade_opt_len;
              ^ points to string after sub string in `cascade_opt`
```

This is just a ways to parse string:

To understand  more clearly what happen in your code, I have written an code:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *cascade_name = NULL;
    char* cascade_opt = "nameIs";   
    int     cascade_opt_len = strlen(cascade_opt);
    int i = 1;
    if( strncmp( argv[i], cascade_opt, cascade_opt_len) == 0 )
        cascade_name = argv[i] + cascade_opt_len;

    printf("\ncascade_name is: %s ", cascade_name);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

lets we execute it(but notice i=1 in code):

```
~$ ./a.out  nameIsGrijesh

cascade_name is: Grijesh
```

now after if statement `cascade_name`  points to 'Grijesh' the last sub string in argv[1].

Ok I extend this code with a loop to parse each input command line arguments:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *cascade_name = NULL;
    char* cascade_opt = "nameIs";   
    int     cascade_opt_len = strlen(cascade_opt);
    int i = 1;
    for(i=1; i < argc; i++){
        if( strncmp( argv[i], cascade_opt, cascade_opt_len) == 0 ){
            cascade_name = argv[i] + cascade_opt_len;
            printf("\ncascade_name is: %s ", cascade_name);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");   
    return 0;
}
```

Now see what is code runs:

```
grijesh@hp:~$ ./a.out nameIsGrijesh nameIsB.rabbit mynameIsXX nameIsStackOverflow

cascade_name is: Grijesh 
cascade_name is: B.rabbit 
cascade_name is: StackOverflow
```

do you understands why `XX` not printed ?

**Edit**

Ok for `== '='` my third code will help: Try to understand output:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *cascade_name = NULL;
    char* cascade_opt = "nameIs";   
    int   cascade_opt_len = strlen(cascade_opt);
    int   nested_cascade_opt_len = strlen(cascade_opt);
    int i = 1;
    for(i=1; i < argc; i++){
        if( strncmp( argv[i], cascade_opt, cascade_opt_len) == 0 ){
            cascade_name = argv[i] + cascade_opt_len;
            printf("\ncascade_name is: %s ", cascade_name);
        }
        if( argv[i][nested_cascade_opt_len] == '=' ){
            cascade_name = argv[i] + nested_cascade_opt_len + 1;
            printf("\nfom second potion is: %s ", cascade_name);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");   
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
:~$ ./a.out  nameIsGrijesh nameIsB.rabbit myname=XX nameIsStackOverflow

cascade_name is: Grijesh 
cascade_name is: B.rabbit 
fom second option is: XX 
cascade_name is: StackOverflow
```

Comment: oh okay thanks! Any idea what ( argv[i][nested_cascade_opt_len] == '=' ) means? Somehow the code works without me typing anything into the visual C++ console. I'm not sure why though :/

Comment: @B.rabbit Yes but try to find your self in my answer, command line input having HINT for `== '='`.

Comment: Yes I think I understand why xx is not printed. xx is not printed because when they compare the first cascade_opt_len characters of argv[3] which is mynameIsXX and the cascade_opt they are not equal and hence the if condition is not satisfied hence it does not print

Comment: @B.rabbit yes you are almost correct, read updated answer

Comment: oh okay I get it! thank you very much!!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

For your first example, it is looking at item 'i' of argv, and asking if it begins with the string contained in `cascade_opt`. If so, it sets `cascade_name` to the remainder. So, if `cascade_opt` contained, for example, `--cascade=`, and argv[i] contained `--cascade=foo', cascade_name would end up pointing to`foo`.

For your second question, think of `argv` as a char*[]. Once you have selected a single char*, you can then use [] to index the characters in the string.

Comment: Ohh. Let me if check if I understood you correctly. so for example in the case of argv[1] being mynameisB.rabbit, argv[1][5] would refer to the letter e?